# .HTACCESS URL Rewriting - 404 Error in My URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying for URL rewriting and using below mentioned code. But I am receiving 404 Error on my pages except one given below.

```
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on

   rewritecond %{http_host} ^phoolwala.net [nc]
   rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.phoolwala.net/$1 [r=301,nc]
   #RewriteRule ^index.php?$ /phoolwala.net/? [R=301] 
   RewriteRule ^index.php?$ /? [R=301] 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    #below line gives error in dhtml editor
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]

    #RewriteRule ^(.*)/$             $1.php [L]


    RewriteRule ^register/$ register.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^register$ register.php [L]


    RewriteRule ^my-account/$ my-account.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^my-account$ my-account.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^track-order/$ track-order.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^track-order$ track-order.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^edit-profile/$ edit-profile.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^edit-profile$ edit-profile.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^testimonials/$ testimonials.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^testimonials$ testimonials.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^sitemap/$ sitemap.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^sitemap$ sitemap.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^login/$ login.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^my-account/$ my-account.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^my-account$ my-account.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^edit-profile/$ edit-profile.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^edit-profile$ edit-profile.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^reminders/$ reminders.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^reminders$ reminders.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^view-my-orders/$ view-my-orders.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^view-my-orders$ view-my-orders.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^order-details/$ order-details.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^order-details$ order-details.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^contact-us/$ contact-us.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^contact-us$ contact-us.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^logout/$ logout.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^cart/$ cart.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^cart$ cart.php [L]


     RewriteRule ^international-products/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ international-products.php?cid=$1&id=$2&pageno=$3 [L]
     RewriteRule ^international-products/(.*)/(.*)(.*)/ international-products.php?cid=$1&id=$2&pageno=$3 [L]

    RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)/ products.php?id=$1&pageno=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*) products.php?id=$1&pageno=$2 [L]

    RewriteRule ^price/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ productsprice.php?from=$1&to=$2&pageno=$3 [L]
    RewriteRule ^price/(.*)/(.*)(.*)/ productsprice.php?from=$1&to=$2&pageno=$3 [L]

    RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/(.*)/ page.php?alias=$1&id=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/(.*) page.php?alias=$1&id=$2 [L]

    RewriteRule ^international-product/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ international-product-details.php?cid=$1&cat=$2&id=$3 [L]
    RewriteRule ^international-product/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) international-product-details.php?cid=$1&cat=$2&id=$3 [L]

    RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ product-details.php?cat=$1&alias=$2&id=$3 [L]
    RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) product-details.php?cat=$1&alias=$2&id=$3 [L]

    RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ productsearch.php?keyword=$1&cat=$2&pageno=$3 [L]
    RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)(.*)/ productsearch.php?keyword=$1&cat=$2&pageno=$3 [L]

    RewriteRule ^international/(.*)/ international.php?cid=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^international/(.*) international.php?cid=$1 [L]
```

But except below code nothing is working please help me to update the code.

```
  RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ product-details.php?cat=$1&alias=$2&id=$3 [L]
  RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) product-details.php?cat=$1&alias=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

Comment: What URL are you requesting and what do you expect to rewrite it to?

Comment: Request URL is : products.php?id=15&pageno=2 and I require products/15/2

Comment: And when you go to `/products.php?id=15&pageno=2`, it works?

Comment: Could you please help me on this?

Comment: I don't see anything that's wrong with the `/products` rewrites. There's some issues with your regular expressions like `(.*)(.*)` which will only match the first grouping, but nothing wrong with `/products`. I put these rules in a blank htaccess file and I go to `/products/15/2` and get served the content at `/products.php?id=15&pageno=2`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply, Today i have also face same problem and i got a solution that i want to share with you.

Don't know it is correct or not because i m beginner in PHP.

```
products.php?id=15&pageno=2 and I require products/15/2
```

I was getting error because of i found that one of my page name is also products.php, when i have changed this `products/15/2` to `product-detail/15/2` and it worked fine!!!

So it means don't declare keyword in htaccess rule that are already a name of page. I think so :)

Thanks